# For loop to get iterate value python

Tags: python

Please help

Below is the code

```
start = 3
end = 5
for x in range(start,  end + 1):
    print x
    #and 
    #print iterate from 0
```

I am looking  here, x will print 3 4 5

and  I also need to print 0 1 2 that first time enter to loop print 0 and second time enter to loop print 1 and so on.

Please help

Comment: `print x, x-start`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python has [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) for just this:

```
start = 3
end = 5
for i, x in enumerate(range(start,  end + 1)):
    print(i, x)
```

which prints:

```
0 3
1 4
2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start = 3
end = 5
counter = 0
for x in range(start,  end + 1):
    print x
    #and 
    #print iterate from 0 
    print counter
    counter += 1
```